# Deriving the Poincare patch from global coordinates in AdS$_{3}$

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, quantum-gravity, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I have been reading Thomas Hartman's [lecture notes](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/) on Quantum Gravity and Black Holes.

---

In page 97, he derives (9.4), which is the metric of AdS$_{3}$ in global 
coordinates:

$$ds^{2} = \ell^{2}(-\cosh^{2}\rho\ dt^{2} + d\rho^{2} + \sinh^{2}\rho\ d\phi^{2}).$$

---

In page 100, he states that, expanding the metric **at large $r$** under the coordinate change
    \begin{align}
    t^{\pm} = t \pm \phi, \qquad \rho = \log(2r),
\end{align}
we can show that, **to leading order**, the induced metric on the hyperboloid AdS$_{3}$ becomes
\begin{align}
    ds^{2} = \ell^{2} \left(\frac{dr^{2}}{r^{2}}-r^{2}dt^{+}dt^{-}\right).
\end{align}

---

I find, under the coordinate change, that
    \begin{align}
    ds^{2} = \ell^{2} \left(\frac{dr^{2}}{r^{2}} - \frac{1}{4}dt^{+2} - \left(r^{2} + \frac{1}{16r^{2}} \right) dt^{+}dt^{-} - \frac{1}{4}dt^{-2} \right).
\end{align}

Of course, the term in $1/r^{2}$ drops off at large $r$, but I am not able to get rid of the components in $dt^{+2}$ and $dt^{-2}$. Am I missing something here?

---

He then goes on to mention that these are Poincare coordinates, but does not make contact with the usual way in which the metric of AdS$_{3}$ is written in Poincare coordinates:

$$ds^{2} = \frac{\ell^{2}}{z^{2}}(dz^{2}-dt^{2}+d\vec{x}^{2}).$$

What am I missing here?

Comment: You could try appendix B of http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/~cpherzog/stringtheory/AdSCFT.pdf.  In answer to your first question, probably he is saying that $dt_\pm^2$ is small compared to $r^2 dt_+ dt_-$.  In answer to the second, there should be relations $r \sim 1/z$ and $t_\pm = t \pm x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that he cut the terms lower than $O(r)$ (except the $dr^2$ term), making your $dt^\pm$ terms, $O(1)$, vanish. I have derived a slightly different result but with a common result. I used the transformation
\begin{equation}
dt^2=(dt^+-d\phi)(dt^--\phi)=dt^+dt^-+d\phi^2
\end{equation}
which brings me to the metric
\begin{equation}
ds^2=l^2\left(\frac{dr^2}{r^2}-\left(r^2+\frac{1}{16r^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)dt^+dt^--d\phi^2\right).
\end{equation}
Cutting the small terms below $O(r)$ will lead you to the right answer. This is indeed in the form of [Poincaré coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space#Poincar.C3.A9_coordinates):
\begin{equation}
ds^2=\alpha^2\left(\frac{du^2}{u^2}+u^2(dx^\mu dx_\mu)\right).
\end{equation}